# What is the actual Compose version of a file if I do not specify a minor version?

Tags: docker

Docker has a [documentation page that lists Compose versions with the version of the Docker Engine they support](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#compose-and-docker-compatibility-matrix). In short:

```
Compose file format    Docker Engine release
--------------------------------------------
3.6                    18.02.0+
3.5                    17.12.0+
3.4                    17.09.0+
3.3                    17.06.0+
3.2                    17.04.0+
3.1                    1.13.1+
3.0                    1.13.0+
...
```

I know I can use a specific major/minor version in my compose file (`version: "3.6"`), but what happens if I do not specify the minor version (`version: "3"`)? Does this behave as "3.0", the latest Compose version installed, or the highest Compose file format that supports the Docker Engine that I have installed?

Say, for sake of example, I have

- Highest installed Compose version is 3.5
- Docker Engine 17.06.0 installed

and I start my Compose file with `version: "3"`. What feature set do I have access to? 3.0, 3.3, 3.5, or 3.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `version: '3'` in your Compose file, it will act as 3.0.

This was confirmed by user [Raj Chaudhuri on the Docker Community Forums](https://forums.docker.com/t/what-is-the-actual-compose-version-of-a-file-if-i-do-not-specify-a-minor-version/52607/2?u=gunr2171).

> You have access to 3.0. You can verify this by running `docker-compose config` on a file with `version: '3'`.

As an example, given this compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  html:
    image: nginx
```

Running `docker-compose.yml --file <filename> config` will produce:

```
services:
  html:
    image: nginx
version: '3.0'
```

---

The other way to test this is by simply making a "3" file that contains features introduced after 3.0. `configs` is a feature added with version 3.3. Running this file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  html:
    image: nginx
    configs:
      - source: myconfig
        target: /tmp/abc.txt

configs:
  myconfig:
    file: ./some-file.txt
```

will produce an error indicating that "configs" is not a valid selection.